# Solution at a particular point

Tags: equation-solving, resolve

I have an equation

```
y[a, b, x] = a^2 b x^-2 (Exp[b/x] - 1)^-1
```

and when I plot, it gives the expected curve as shown in the image attached.

[image: Equation Plot]

I need to find the value of `x` at the intersecting point, marked with a circle. For a large number of the parameters `a` and `b`, I could find the solution and select the value of `x` at `x=1`, but it will give two different points.

For varying `a` and `b`, the line will also shift accordingly.
How should I do it?

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code about your picture.

Comment: The equation is given in the plot. It is y[a,b,x]=a^2*b*x^{-2}* Exp[(b/x)-1]^{-1}, then just did the ```LogLogPlot```

Comment: @Pritam next time, please do make some effort to craft a reasonably good question.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: You write you wanted to find the value of `x` but selected an answer that does not do that. That's very confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice you have a syntax problem in your code, the correct way to define your function is like this

```
y[a_, b_, x_] = a^2 b x^-2 (Exp[b/x] - 1)^-1
```

Now you can [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for the parameter `a`, for any `b` and `x`

```
Solve[y[a, b, x] ==1,{a}]
```

[image]

Now you have an expression for `a`, that you can replace with any `x` and `b` that makes sense.

If you want only the solution to the left, then you can use [`Min`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html) to get

```
Min[a/.Solve[y[a, b, x] ==1,{a}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on what the OP is doing, it might be numerically advantageous to reformulate the solution as `x Exp[b/(4 x)] Sqrt[2/b Sinh[b/(2 x)]]` (and its negative).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming (1) you really did mean, "I need to find the value of `x`....", (2) that "marked with a circle" is code for the minimum positive value of `x`, then `Solve[]` can do it. (I'll use the variant `SolveValues[]` for convenience.)

```
solveForX[a_, b_] := Min@SolveValues[
    a^2 b x^-2 (Exp[b/x] - 1)^-1 == 1 && x > 0,
    x, 
    Reals];

solveForX[1, 1/10]
(*
Root[{-1 - 10 #1^2 + 10 E^(1/(10 #1)) #1^2 &, 
  0.0171457002528354157999}]
*)
```

If you don't like `Root` objects or have to use the result outside of Mathematica, then `N[]` may be used to convert the solution to any desired precision.

```
N[solveForX[1, 1/10]]
(*  0.0171457  *)
```

Or if you use floating-point inputs, you'll get a floating-point output:

```
solveForX[1., 0.1]
(*  0.0171457  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

We set `a`,`b` and the leval set `c` varying and find the root `x`.

```
f[{a_, b_}][x_] = a^2 b x^-2 (Exp[b/x] - 1)^-1;
root[p_?VectorQ][c_] := NSolveValues[f[p][x] == c, x, Reals];
pt[p_?VectorQ][c_] := 
  If[Length[ root[p][c]] >= 2, {Log@First@root[p][c], Log@c} // Point,
    Nothing];
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[{f[p][x], c} // Evaluate, {x, 0.02, 1000}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], pt[p][c]}]], {{p, {3, 2}}, {2, 
   2}, {10, 10}}, {c, .5, 1.5}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]